# I want to print originalTitle cast overview posterURLs": "154"

Tags: python, json

I want to print
originalTitle
cast
overview
posterURLs": "154"

Python

```
import requests

url = "https://streaming-availabil"

querystring = {"country":"us","language":"en"}

headers = {
   "X-RapidAPI-Host": "streaming-availabil",
   "X-RapidAPI-Key": "2883887409m"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)



print(response.text)
```

JSON Results

```
{"results":[{"imdbID":"tt9850370","tmdbID":"610643","imdbRating":65,"imdbVoteCount":1513,"tmdbRating":69,"backdropPath":"/pYziM5SEmptPW0LdNhWvjzR2zD1.jpg","backdropURLs":{"1280":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/pYziM5SEmptPW0LdNhWvjzR2zD1.jpg","300":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/pYziM5SEmptPW0LdNhWvjzR2zD1.jpg","780":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/pYziM5SEmptPW0LdNhWvjzR2zD1.jpg","original":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/pYziM5SEmptPW0LdNhWvjzR2zD1.jpg"},"originalTitle":"#AnneFrank. Parallel Stories","genres":[18,36],"countries":["IT"],"year":2019,"runtime":92,"cast":["Helen Mirren","Anne Frank","Martina Gatti","Arianna Szorenyi"],"significants":["Sabina Fedeli","Anna Migotto"],"title":"#AnneFrank. Parallel Stories","overview":"One single Anne Frank moves us more than the countless others who suffered just as she did but whose faces have remained in the shadows-Primo Levi. The Oscar®-winning Helen Mirren will introduce audiences to Anne Frank's story through the words in her diary. The set will be her room in the secret refuge in Amsterdam, reconstructed in every detail by set designers from the Piccolo Theatre in Milan. Anne Frank this year would have been 90 years old. Anne's story is intertwined with that of five Holocaust survivors, teenage girls just like her, with the same ideals, the same desire to live: Arianna Szörenyi, Sarah Lichtsztejn-Montard, Helga Weiss and sisters Andra and Tatiana Bucci. Their testimonies alternate with those of their children and grandchildren.","tagline":"","video":"FzT7-NfkxLA","posterPath":"/hkC4yNDFmW1yQuQhtZydMeRuaAb.jpg","posterURLs":{"154":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/hkC4yNDFmW1yQuQhtZydMeRuaAb.jpg","185":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/hkC4yNDFmW1yQuQhtZydMeRuaAb.jpg","342":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/hkC4yNDFmW1yQuQhtZydMeRuaAb.jpg","500":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/hkC4yNDFmW1yQuQhtZydMeRuaAb.jpg","780":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/hkC4yNDFmW1yQuQhtZydMeRuaAb.jpg","92":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/hkC4yNDFmW1yQuQhtZydMeRuaAb.jpg","original":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/hkC4yNDFmW1yQuQhtZydMeRuaAb.jpg"},"age":10,"streamingInfo":{"netflix":{"us":{"link":"https://www.netflix.com/title/81264660/","added":1600283847,"leaving":0}}},"originalLanguage":"en"},{"imdbID":"tt5616176","tmdbID":"710356","imdbRating":62,"imdbVoteCount":3445,"tmdbRating":77,"backdropPath":"/97aoG9EsExPflrUO8eEbnARaeZH.jpg","backdropURLs":{"1280":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/97aoG9EsExPflrUO8eEbnARaeZH.jpg","300":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/97aoG9EsExPflrUO8eEbnARaeZH.jpg","780":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/97aoG9EsExPflrUO8eEbnARaeZH.jpg","original":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/97aoG9EsExPflrUO8eEbnARaeZH.jpg"},"originalTitle":"2 Hearts","genres":[18,10749],"countries":["US"],"year":2020,"runtime":100,"cast":["Jacob Elordi","Adan Canto","Tiera Skovbye","Radha Mitchell","Kari Matchett","Tahmoh Penikett","Steve Bacic"],"significants":["Lance Hool"],"title":"2 Hearts","overview":"When illness strikes two people who are polar opposites, life and death bring them together in surprising ways.","tagline":"Discover the mystery that connects them all.","video":"OjqewZT0r68","posterPath":"/a7bW3uKOMPBnmHs8gnlpfhTD8YQ.jpg","posterURLs":{"154":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/a7bW3uKOMPBnmHs8gnlpfhTD8YQ.jpg","185":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/a7bW3uKOMPBnmHs8gnlpfhTD8YQ.jpg","342":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/a7bW3uKOMPBnmHs8gnlpfhTD8YQ.jpg","500":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/a7bW3uKOMPBnmHs8gnlpfhTD8YQ.jpg","780":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/a7bW3uKOMPBnmHs8gnlpfhTD8YQ.jpg","92":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/a7bW3uKOMPBnmHs8gnlpfhTD8YQ.jpg","original":"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/a7bW3uKOMPBnmHs8gnlpfhTD8YQ.jpg"},"age":11,"streamingInfo":{"netflix":{"us":{"link":"https://www.netflix.com/title/81435805/","added":1622682722,"leaving":0}}},"originalLanguage":"en"},
```

Comment: Are you sure it's okay to have that RapidAPI-Host and Key be published publicly?

Comment: OK, then do it.  You have a dictionary with one key, which contains a list.  You to a `for` loop over that list and print the keys you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is just straightfoward trolling through a Python data structure.

```
for res in response.json()['results']:
    print( res['originalTitle'] )
    print( res['cast'] )
    print( res['overview'] )
    print( res['posterURLs']['154'] )
```